# Iterating generic array of any type in Java

Tags: java, generics, loops

If there is an instance of Java Collection which may carry primitive type, generic array, and/or iterable collection, I want to treat the generic array as Iterable collection, but how? e.g. the following pseudo java code

```
List<?> list1; 
list1.add(new int[2]); 
list1.add(new String[3]); 
list1.add(new ArrayList());
for (Object e : list1){
    if (e instanceof Iterable){ 
        //The int[2] and String[3] will not fall in this case that I want it be
        //Iterate within e
    }
}
```

Please advise how to make the int[2] and String[3] fall in the case.

Thanks & regards,
William

Comment: I could be wrong(I often am), but I think I provided answer where you could iterate over generic collections without knowing exact type.

Comment: @Petro Semeniuk: Your solution works but it makes arrays a special case and treats them differently. The spirit of the original question (at least as I interpreted it) was how can we avoid doing that. How can we make arrays behave just like our other Iterables without treating them separately.

Comment: @Asaph. Thanks. I really misunderstood original question. Wrapping arrays into collection is really the best solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your loop, you could use the appropriate array operand for `instanceof`.

For `int[]`:

```
if (e instanceof int[]) {
   // ...
}
```

For `Object` arrays (including `String[]`):

```
if (e instanceof Object[]){
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, when adding your arrays to your master `List`, you could wrap each one in [`Arrays.asList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29). In that case, you could use the `List<List>` generic instead of the wildcard generic `List<?>` and avoid the need to check the data type with `instanceof`. Something like this:

```
List<List> list1; 
list1.add(Arrays.asList(new int[2])); 
list1.add(Arrays.asList(new String[3])); 
list1.add(new ArrayList());
for (List e : list1){
    // no need to check instanceof Iterable because we guarantee it's a List
    for (Object object : e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Anytime you're using `instanceof` and generics together, it's a smell that you may be doing something not quite right with your generics.

Comment: is it possible to do something like: "e instanceof T[]", where T is type parameter <T>?

Comment: @William Choi: No. That is not possible because of type erasure. `instanceof` happens at runtime and `T[]` is lost after compile time.

Comment: got it. I've misunderstood that the T[] will be kept during run-time.

Comment: If all you need to do with the items is iterate over them, use a `List<Iterable>`, not a `List<List>`.  That way you have the flexibility to store other iterable things like `Set` as well.

Answer (score 11):

Use Array class from reflection package:

```
    final List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
    list.add(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" });
    final List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("el1");
    list.add(arrayList);

    for (Object element : list) {
        if (element instanceof Iterable) {
            for (Object objectInIterable : (Iterable) element) {
                System.out.println(objectInIterable);
            }
        }
        if (element.getClass().isArray()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(element); i++) {
                System.out.println(Array.get(element, i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't add things to a `List<?>`.  If you want a list of heterogeneous things, use a `List<Object>`.

However, since you want to iterate over the things in your list, why not use a `List<Iterable<Object>>`?  To add an array, use `Arrays.asList(myarray)` to get something that implements `Iterable` from it.

```
final List<Iterable<? extends Object>> list1 = new ArrayList<Iterable<? extends Object>>();

list1.add(Arrays.asList(new int[2]));
list1.add(Arrays.asList(new String[3])); 
list1.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

for (final Iterable<? extends Object> e : list1) {
    for (final Object i : e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you want to store non-iterable things in your list too, then you'll need to use `List<Object>` and the `instanceof` check, but you can still use `Arrays.asList()` to turn arrays into iterables, avoiding the need to handle arrays as a special case.

Comment: Yup, we can't add element into List<?>. But we can use List<?> in method arguments. I'm just trying to illustrate such case, sorry for making confuse. Return to the question, i'm really curious about if there exists a way to do something like "e instanceof T[]" where "T" is type parameter.

Comment: @William Choi, no, you can't do that, because the type parameter T only exists at compile time; at runtime it's effectively just Object.  If you need to know the parameterized type at runtime, you can make the caller pass in a parameter of type `Class<T>`.  The compiler will enforce that only the correct class object can be passed, and you can use methods like `isInstance()`, `isArray()`, and `getComponentType()` on the class object.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays do not implement the Iterable interface.

```
public class StackOverflow
{
    public static void main(final String[] argv)
    {
        display(new int[0].getClass());
    }

    private static void display(final Class clazz)
    {
        final Class   superClass;
        final Class[] interfaces;

        superClass = clazz.getSuperclass();

        if(superClass != null)
        {
            display(superClass);
        }

        System.out.println(clazz.getCanonicalName());
        interfaces = clazz.getInterfaces();

        for(final Class iface : interfaces)
        {
            display(iface);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.Object
int[]
java.lang.Cloneable
java.io.Serializable
```

You can use `isArray()` on the class to see if it is an array:

```
public class StackOverflow
{
    public static void main(final String[] argv)
    {
        List<Object> list1;

        list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list1.add(new int[2]);
        list1.add(new String[3]);
        list1.add(new ArrayList());

        for(Object e : list1)
        {
            if(e instanceof Iterable)
            {
                System.out.println("Iterable");
            }

            if(e.getClass().isArray())
            {
                System.out.println("array");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class IterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();

        list1.add(new int[] { 0, 1, 2 });
        list1.add(new String[] { "SA_0", "SA_1", "SA_2" });
        list1.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "L_0", "L_1", "L_2" }));

        for (Object e : list1) {
            if (e instanceof Iterable) {
                iterate((Iterable) e);
            } else if (e.getClass().isArray()) {
                iterateArray(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void iterateArray(Object e) {
        Class type = e.getClass().getComponentType();
        if (!type.isPrimitive())        { iterate((Object[])  e); }
        else if (type == boolean.class) { iterate((boolean[]) e); }
        else if (type == double.class)  { iterate((double[])  e); } 
        else if (type == float.class)   { iterate((float[])   e); } 
        else if (type == short.class)   { iterate((short[])   e); } 
        else if (type == long.class)    { iterate((long[])    e); } 
        else if (type == char.class)    { iterate((char[])    e); }
        else if (type == byte.class)    { iterate((byte[])    e); } 
        else if (type == int.class)     { iterate((int[])     e); } 
    }

    static void iterate(Iterable  a) { for (Object  e : a) { print(e); } }
    static void iterate(Object[]  a) { for (Object  e : a) { print(e); } }
    static void iterate(boolean[] a) { for (boolean e : a) { print(e); } }
    static void iterate(double[]  a) { for (double  e : a) { print(e); } }
    static void iterate(float[]   a) { for (float   e : a) { print(e); } }
    static void iterate(short[]   a) { for (short   e : a) { print(e); } }
    static void iterate(long[]    a) { for (long    e : a) { print(e); } }
    static void iterate(char[]    a) { for (char    e : a) { print(e); } }
    static void iterate(byte[]    a) { for (byte    e : a) { print(e); } }
    static void iterate(int[]     a) { for (int     e : a) { print(e); } }

    static void print(Object o) { System.out.println(o); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generics

```
public void printArray(T[] someArray) {
    for (T t : someArray)
        System.out.println(t);        
}
```